# How to transfer 3.5 million records from one Access 2010 table to another

Tags: query, ms-access-2010

Because my table has over 3.5 million records I'm having issues with changing the data type in certain fields in the original table (Table A).  Since it's so big I can't simply copy and paste the entire table and if I went with the 65,000 record limit, I'd have to do it 54 times, which I'd rather not do.

I created a "Copy of A" (structure only), fixed the data type and tried an append query, but that didn't work either.  It couldn't open the table.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: To copy data from tableA to tableB you must run one simple query, and the only problem you can meet is 2Gb database filesize limit. So I cannot understand what you're asking about...

Comment: The database is 1.06 GB already.  I really want to change the data type of  a few fields from Text to Number.  I get an out of memory error if I try to do it directly in the table.  So I created a copy of A (structure only) and am just trying to append the data from A to the Copy of A (with the new data types), but that too isn't working.

Comment: *The database is 1.06 GB already.* To alter the table you must create new table in another database file and copy your data (with all changes you beed) into it.

Comment: But how to copy 3.5 million records?  I can only copy 65,000 at a time as the limit of the clipboard.

Comment: Clipboard? that's your problems. A have said: *you must run one simple query*. `INSERT .. SELECT`, and all records are copied. Or use Import master.